# Unable to access java.sql.DatabaseMetaData to determine appropriate Dialect to use

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to upgrade to my hibernate version 3.2 to 4.1.0 and at
the same time integrating with spring 4.3.10, I have configured well
and running my project in tomcat server but when it comes to jboss I
am getting following exception. can someone solve my issue, I am not
getting what mistake I am doing.

```
    Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scmController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scm_service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scmServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scmdao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scmDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up DRSCM1, service service jboss.naming.context.java.DRSCM1 is not started
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up DRSCM1, service service jboss.naming.context.java.DRSCM1 is not started
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up DRSCM1, service service jboss.naming.context.java.DRSCM1 is not started
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up DRSCM1, service service jboss.naming.context.java.DRSCM1 is not started
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3593) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3802) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Libs:

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
apache-logging-log4j.jar
asm-5.1.jar
axis.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-discovery-0.2.jar
commons-email-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar
commons-io-1.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.2-javadoc.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dumbster-1.6.jar
gson-2.2.3.jar
gwtx-1.5.0.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
icu4j-4.8.1.jar
itext-2.1.7.jar
jackson-annotations-2.8.10.jar
jackson-core-2.8.10.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jasperreports-3.7.6.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
jaxrpc.jar
jboss-jmx-4.2.2.GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jboss-system-4.0.2.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
jsp-api-2.2.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jxl-2.6.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
lucene-core-2.3.2.jar
lucene-highlighter-2.0.0.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
poi-3.6.jar
postgresql-9.3-1104-jdbc4.jar
quartz-1.5.2.jar
saaj.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
wsdl4j.jar
xom-1.0.jar
```

> DaoImplementation:

```
@Repository
public class scmDaoImpl implements scmDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

> Service Implementation:

```
@Service
public class scmServiceImpl implements scmService {


    @Autowired
    private scmDao scmdao;

    public scmDao getScmdao() {
        return scmdao;
    }

    public void setScmdao(scmDao scmdao) {
        this.scmdao = scmdao;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ScmController {


    @Autowired
    private scmService scm_service;

    public scmService getScm_service() {
        return scm_service;
    }

    public void setScm_service(scmService scm_service) {
        this.scm_service = scm_service;
    }

    HttpSession session;

    public HttpSession getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(HttpSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

}
```

Dispatcher Servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.nic.scm" />
     <context:annotation-config />
     <mvc:annotation-driven /> 
     <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"  />

     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" /> 



     <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:/DRSCM1" resource-ref="true"/>


     <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">scm</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                </prop>


                  <prop key="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners"> false</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

     <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Just set the dialect. You are using the wrong property it should be `hibernate.dialect` not `dialect`. If there is no dialect configured Hibernate will try to detect it based on the connection.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I have updated dialect to hibernate.dialect, but this time I am getting this exception           Bean property 'java:/DRSCM1' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: Without a fullstacktrace it is impossible to answer (and doesn't seem related).

Comment: Dear @M.Deinum, updated stack trace also.

Comment: Check your beans.. You had `<jee:jndi-lookup />` and replaced it with the bare bones `JndiObjectFactoryBean` which you configured wrong. There is no property with that name (as the stacktrace suggests). You probably want `jndiName` instead as the property `name`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I used <jee:jndi-lookup />, but when I use this I am getting following exception, I am trying to different ways. Now I updated to <jee:jndi-lookup /> and getting this exception :  Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up DRSCM1, service service jboss.naming.context.java.DRSCM1 is not started

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thank you for your quick response, I have updated stacktrace and dispatcher-servlet.

Comment: That is something JBOss related I guess. In your configuration the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` will break proper transaction management, remove it and that light also the `hibernate.connection` properties are useless as you are injecting a `DataSource`.

Comment: Dear @M.Deinum, you saved me, this solved my problem, thank you

Comment: Dear @M.Deinum, now I am getting javax.naming.NameNotFoundException, can you please solve my problem